# Flutter || Firestore: how to retrieve data from firestore and display it in the DataTable

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, datatable

I am trying to retrieve data from firestore and display it on the DataTable. Everything works perfectly fine but I am having a problem with creating a list of DataRow for each user info.

```
 List<DataRow> buildList(allData){
    List? dataRowList;
    for(int i =0; i <allData.length; i++){
      DataRow(cells: [
        DataCell(
          Text(allData[i]['customerNumber']),
        ),
        DataCell(Text(allData[i]['Name'])),
        DataCell(Text(allData[i]['TCKN'])),
        DataCell(Text(allData[i]['VKN'])),
        DataCell(Text(allData[i]['paketAdi'])),
        DataCell(
          Text(
            allData[i]['status'],
            style: TextStyle(
                color: allData[i]['status'] == "Tamamlandı"
                    ? Colors.green
                    : allData[i]['status'] == "İşlem Başarısız"
                    ? Colors.red
                    : allData[i]['status'] ==
                    "Belgeler Bankada"
                    ? Colors.cyanAccent
                    : Colors.blue),
          ),
        ),
        DataCell(Text(allData[i]['startDate'])),
        DataCell(Text(allData[i]['endDate'])),
      ]);
    }
    return null;
  }
```

How can I return list of DataRows and use them as follow:

```
FutureBuilder(
            future: getUserInfoData(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List> snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) return LinearProgressIndicator();
              List? allData = snapshot.data;
              return DataTable(
                columnSpacing: 22,
                columns: [
                  DataColumn(label: Text('Müşteri No')),
                  DataColumn(label: Text('İsim Soyisim')),
                  DataColumn(label: Text('TCKN')),
                  DataColumn(label: Text('VKN')),
                  DataColumn(label: Text('Paket Adı')),
                  DataColumn(label: Text('Paket Durumu')),
                  DataColumn(label: Text('Baslangic Tarih')),
                  DataColumn(label: Text('Bitis Tarih')),
                ],
                rows: buildList(allData),
              );
            },
          )
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those of you who are looking for an answer to that question, this is how I figured it out;

I modified the buildList;

```
DataRow buildList(allData, i) {
    return DataRow(cells: [
      DataCell(
        Text(allData[i]['customerNumber']),
      ),
      DataCell(Text(allData[i]['Name'])),
      DataCell(Text(allData[i]['TCKN'])),
      DataCell(Text(allData[i]['VKN'])),
      DataCell(Text(allData[i]['paketAdi'])),
      DataCell(
        Text(
          allData[i]['status'],
          style: TextStyle(
              color: allData[i]['status'] == "Tamamlandı"
                  ? Colors.green
                  : allData[i]['status'] == "İşlem Başarısız"
                      ? Colors.red
                      : allData[i]['status'] == "Belgeler Bankada"
                          ? Colors.cyanAccent
                          : Colors.blue),
        ),
      ),
      DataCell(Text(allData[i]['startDate'])),
      DataCell(Text(allData[i]['endDate'])),
    ]);
  }
```

And this is how you call this function;

```
 rows: List.generate(allData.length, (index) =>
                          buildList(allData, index))
```